# C++ including Python.h compiling using makefile

Tags: python, c++, linux, makefile

I am trying to compile a C++ program which uses `Python.h` to execute some python scripts. Before adding the python, I had a makefile which works perfectly. I added the code to run the python script, which involves including the `Python.h` file.

I edited the makefile to include this file, without success.

My makefile:

```
CC          = g++
SHELL       = /bin/sh
EXECUTABLES = Software_V2
CFLAGS      += -O2 -g0 -Wall -pedantic -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c99 $(shell python3-config --cflags)
LIBS         = -lm -lrt -laes_access -lstdc++ -pthread

OBJS = $(EXECUTABLES).o 

.PHONEY: all
all:    $(EXECUTABLES)

.PHONEY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.[bo]
    rm -f *.err
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLES)

$(EXECUTABLES): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@
```

I already installed following libraries:

- `sudo apt-get install python-dev`
- `sudo apt-get install python3-dev`
- `sudo apt install libpython3.7-dev`

The error after running `make` I'm receiving the following error:

```
g++    -c -o Software_V2.o Software_V2.cpp
Software_V2.cpp:3:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: Software_V2.o] Error 1
```

I also tried changing the include from `#include <Python.h>` to `#include <python3.7m/Python.h>`

None of my tries succeeded, I'm out of inspiration at this moment to try some new things, maybe you guys know how to solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Check if python3-config --cflags fives you what you expect. Check the -I directories to make sure that the file is in one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing C and C++.  These are completely different languages: you shouldn't confuse them.

In makefiles, the default rules use `CC` to hold the C compiler and `CXX` to hold the C++ compiler.  Similarly, they use `CFLAGS` to hold flags for the C compiler and `CXXFLAGS` to hold flags for the C++ compiler.

In your makefile you've not set either the `CXX` or the `CXXFLAGS` variables, but you're trying to use the default rule to build your object file.  The default value for `CXX` is `g++` (on your system) and the default value for `CXXFLAGS` is empty.  That's why when make shows you the compile command, none of your options appear there:

```
 g++    -c -o Software_V2.o Software_V2.cpp
```

If you're trying to compile C++ code (implied by the fact that your filename extension is `.cpp` not `.c`) then you should set `CXXFLAGS` not `CFLAGS`.

Also, it's wrong to set `-std=c99` if you're trying to compile C++; that flag sets the C 1999 standard, not C++.

Comment: Also you shouldn't add `-lc++` to your link line.  If you link with the `g++` front-end then it will automatically add the C++ STL library in the right place.  By adding it specifically you might do it wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I started from scratch rewriting the makefile. This solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try `include "Python.h"` - when you use <> the pre-compiler looks in a different set of directories.

Also run `python3-config --cflags` on the command line and make sure it gives you the right include directories - the Python.h file should be in one of them.

Ultimately, the problem is that the file is not being found in the standard directories that the pre-complier checks, nor in the directories that you specified (with the -I option).